# HHVM graceful restart in CentOS 6.5

Tags: php, centos, hhvm

Is there a way to gracefully restart HHVM?

I've tried to find it in the HHVM documentation but couldn't find anything

Comment: A SIGHUP will do a graceful stop. Combining that with a new start should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love this feature, something like in nginx or apache like 'reload'.
Unfortunatly as of 3.2 the only option is to stop then start the hhvm service.